# NSMutable array removeAllObject removing objects in other NSMutable array too

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I have three class namely **DepartmentViewController**, **DepartmentRequest**, **Department**. Its like im making a department request from **DepartmentViewcontroller** and based on response im manipulating repsonse and adding in NSmutableArray ***responseArray** in **DepartmentRequest** class. This array just contains Department object. I want this **responseArray** in **DepartmentViewController** for searching and reloading tableview. so i passed this array to **DepartmentViewController** through delegate and assigning **responseArray** to **localArray**. Now I did searching based on these two array but if i remove any one of the array using **removeallobject**. Its removing object in other Array too.

```
if(searchString.length>0)
  {

      [localArray removeAllObjects];
    for (int i =0 ; i < [departmentRequest.responseArray count]; i++) {
      Department *dept = [departmentRequest.responseArray objectAtIndex:i];

        if (([dept.departmentName rangeOfString:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)].location != NSNotFound)
          )

        {
                   [localArray addObject:dept];
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"deptname %@",dept.departmentName);
        }

    }

    [departmentTableView reloadData];
```

if i remove object in localArray its removing objects both in departmentReqeust.responseArray and localArray

Comment: are you directly assigning using localArray = responseArray ?

Comment: It sounds like you think you have two arrays and there is actually only one. You are likely passing a reference, not a clone. The code you have supplied is not enough to determine if that is the case or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should assign like

> localArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:responseArray];

Comment: localArray is also MutableArray, so I changed to [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseArray]. thank you

Comment: or localArray = [responseArray mutableCopy]

Answer (score 0):

if(searchString.length>0)
  {

```
 // [localArray removeAllObjects];

 NSMutableArray arrTemp=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i =0 ; i < [departmentRequest.responseArray count]; i++) {
  Department *dept = [departmentRequest.responseArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if (([dept.departmentName rangeOfString:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)].location != NSNotFound)
      )

    {
               [arrTemp addObject:dept];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"deptname %@",dept.departmentName);
    }

}
localArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:arrTemp];

[departmentTableView reloadData];
```